# Modeling a manufacture wind power curve in Python

Tags: python

I'm having issues with my basic code to analyse a plot of power in Python.
I'm receiving the speed values of a csv file to later be plotted together with the linear regression for later data filter design

```
import numpy
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy


df_dados = pd.read_csv('dados.csv', index_col=0, parse_dates=['timestamp'])  
x=np.array(df_dados['Speed']) #contains array of 95000 lines tipe float
```

#coeficient for linear regression

```
x1=np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,25.01,50])#.reshape((-1,1))
y1=np.array([0,3.0,25.0,82.0,174.0,321.0,532.0,815.0,1180.0,1580.0,1810.0,1980.0,2050.0,2050.0,2050.0,2050.0,2050.0,2050.0,2050.0,2050.0,2050.0,2050.0,2050.0,2050.0,2050.0,0,0])

plt.plot(x1,y1,'-')
plt.xlabel('vento m/s', fontsize=10)
plt.ylabel('potencia Kw', fontsize=10)
plt.show()
```

Until then no problem, but now i want to see for the values of my dataset how the points will behave

```
power_kW = numpy.interp(x,x1,y1)
plt.plot(power_kW,'.')
plt.show()
```

but for this plot i only get the values of speed to the index of time/dates
Anyone knows a way to get trough or am i just thinking it wrong?

Best regards

Comment: You have to use the `plot` function with both the `x` and `y` data explicitly stated to have the real values in both axes (as in your second code snippet).